# How to select children in CSS

Tags: css

This is a fragment of my CSS:

```
div.orgChart  div.node.level2 {
    background-image      : linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #00C)!important;
}
```

Now I need to add another rule for all children from level 3 and down:

**div.orgChart  div.node.level3, div.orgChart  div.node.level4, div.orgChart  div.node.level5** etc

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example HTML where you mark which ones would you like to select?

Comment: I need to select all levels higher than level 3:
div.orgChart div.node.level3, div.orgChart div.node.level4, div.orgChart div.node.level5 etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select this with css3.

I would do it another way: first select all nodes and then override level2:

```
div.orgChart  div.node {
    background-image: Something here that should be used for all these non level2 nodes;
}

div.orgChart  div.node.level2 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #00C)!important;
}
```

Because of the specificity `level2` will get the second definition and not the first. Be sure to override all the stuff that was defined in the first definition.

Comment: Can we do it somehow as children selection, i.e. using ">"?

Comment: Nope, that will only select the children (not the siblings, which is what you want to do)